# Golfer’s elbow (Inner elbow pain) from drop bars?

Tags: road-bike, pain

I’ve been cycling for 3-4 years on a flat bars without any pain in My joints . recently I switched to drop bars, My arms are slightly bent when I ride so My bike fit is ok But I’m having an inner elbow pain in My right hand only after 15-20 minutes of riding.

I also placed My hands on the flat part of the bar and same pain.

Is this a common thing on drop bars to beginners?

Comment: Do you still have the flat bar bike ?  If so, set each up in turn and take a photo from exactly the same place, of the bike's right hand side.  Then overlay them to compare.  Even better is you to sit on each bike and hold the same leg position while holding bars as normal.  Get an assistant to take the photos and then compare them to see the differences.

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t have the flat bar anymore.